# Acessing shadow DOM elements with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, automation, shadow-dom

Basically, I want to acess acess a button that appears in a print preview pop up, which is a shadow dom element. I tried some solutions I found around stackoverflow, but they didn't work, just as the current code I'm trying to build up from, which is:

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC



driver = webdriver.Chrome()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)



def expand_shadow_root(element):

    shadow_root = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", element)

    return shadow_root


root1 = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("print-preview-button-strip")

shadow_root1 = expand_shadow_root(root1)

btn = shadow_root1.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/print-preview-app//print-preview-sidebar//print- 
preview-button-strip//cr-button[1]")

wait.until((EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.XPATH,"/html/body/print-preview-app//print-preview- 
sidebar//print-preview-button-strip//cr-button[1]")))

btn.click()
```

[Inspect Element print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hvSq.png)

Answer (score 0):

try below xpath :

```
 //cr-button[@class='action-button' and @role='button']
```

Comment: When the print preview pop up shows up nothing happens. No error message, but the button isn't clicked.

Comment: can you share your link ?will quickly check from my end

Comment: Here: http://www.portaltransparencia.gov.br/sancoes/ceis?paginacaoSimples=true&tamanhoPagina=&offset=&direcaoOrdenacao=asc&cpfCnpj=26878347000125&colunasSelecionadas=linkDetalhamento%2CcpfCnpj%2Cnome%2CufSancionado%2Corgao%2CtipoSancao%2CdataPublicacao%2Cquantidade&ordenarPor=nome&direcao=asc#                                                                                                           The print preview will pop up when you click on the 'imprimir' button.

Answer (score -1):

In case anyone has the same problem, just insert "-kiosk-printing" as an argument, like this:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("-kiosk-printing")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Solved the problem for me.